# i am not be able to add new product in odoo

Tags: drupal-7, odoo

I am new to odoo openerp. I am trying to integrate odoo with my drupal website. All the required settings and authentication is done. 
Now I am trying to add new product in odoo via its in built modules like sales and products modules.

I have installed some most common modules like crm, sales, products, accounting, etc.
But when I try to add new product, after filling all details I got this warning error "One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try after refreshing."

I do not have any idea whats going wrong. What I am missing?

Comment: What does the http log say?

Comment: show  traceback here

Comment: sorry to say, but how can i get http logs and traceback?